# Is there way to make generic Atom in Recoil

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

I made a atom with Recoil but I couldn't find a way to represent generic atom in Typescript.

```
const atom = atom<T[]>({ // <- I get error
  key: 'atom',
  default: []
})

const value = useRecoilValue<number[]>(atom) // <- specify actual value here (not working now)
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of `atom` function [here](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/blob/main/typescript/recoil.d.ts#L133), `atom` already has a generic type parameter and this should work:

```
const some = atom<string[]>({
  key: 'some-key',
  default: [] // now has `string[]` type
})
```

And from the definition of `useRecoilValue` [we see](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/blob/main/typescript/recoil.d.ts#L223), that generic infers automatically and you don't need to specify it:

```
const value = useRecoilValue(some) // inferred type of `value` is `string[]`
```

You should not specify type at `useRecoilValue` because atom already has this information